# docRef.listCollections is not a function

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, collections

I'm trying to get all the collections from a doc. I'm using firebase 8.10.0 in my react project. I keep getting the same error message over and over again:

> docRef.listCollections is not a function

Here is my simplified code :

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebase.firestore();
const docRef = db.collection("users").doc("communibility");

docRef
  .listCollections()
  .then((collections) => {
    collections.forEach((collection) => {
      console.log(collection.id);
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting collections:", error);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `listCollections` method is not available in the Firebase client library - its only available in the [server client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document).

However, the [Firebase REST API does have an endpoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/listCollectionIds) to list the subcollection IDs under a document. You can use that to get the collection IDs on the client side.

- [Client Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#collection)
- [Server Reference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#listCollections)

Comment: What fix are you proposing?

Comment: If you know your collection names, just use those, or as the Firebase docs say, restructure your data.

Comment: The collections add up over time and get generated automatically. Does that mean there is nothing I can use anymore such as getCollections()?

Comment: Note that the REST API requires OAuth scopes, so won't work for users who are signed into Firebase Authentication (with another provider): https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/listCollectionIds#authorization-scopes